# Hide toolbar elements on specific Magento category page

Tags: magento

I have a custom homepage on my Magento store which displays the latest 150 added products, with the most recent first.

The paging on the toolbar is needed here (30 per page, 5 pages) but the "sort by" and the "Show" number to display are both irrelevant.

The page is constructed using Tridian New Arrivals code (google it), with a minor tweak to sort the collection by entity_id descending, as the created_at sort (suggested in the article) seems to not work correctly.

So this is basically a home page redirect to a category page, which has an over-ride in place to display a specific product collection (the new arrivals).

Could someone show me how to hide those two select lists on just this page please?

Cheers,
Rob

Comment: Would it kill you to add links to the Tridian code and "the article" in your question? It'd remove any ambiguity in your question.

Comment: Ordinarily, no, but in this instance yes as I was on my iPhone, and putting links in is a royal pain. Googling the text I posted returns the correct item first (http://www.tridian.com/developer-blog/adding-new-arrivals-to-magento/). I normally would have done this first time round :-)

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically this is possible with a layout update in the category design, but it has not been so easy:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/46823/#t331000

You can create a new theme that consists of just the files needed to be changed to get rid of the toolbar (hacked phtml file) and then set the custom design for this category to this theme. It will use your default theme to fill in the gaps, e.g. header, footer etc.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this in code, in toolbar.phtml, as follows:

First I set a current category variable at the start of the code (mine is at line 36).

```
<?php
if (Mage::registry('current_category') != NULL) {
    $curr_category = Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();
    $curr_category = strtolower($curr_category);
} else {
    $curr_category = '';
}
?>
```

Then I test the variable value in an IF statement around the code blocks that build and output the select lists.

```
<?php if($curr_category != 'new arrivals'): ?>
--- Select list code here --- 
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope that helps someone!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked for me.  Copy /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml and put it in your /app/design/frontend/default/[your template]/template/catalog/product/list/ as toolbar_new.phtml .

Create a cms page and add this to the layout update :

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_list"  name="product_list" template="catalog/product/ga_gallery.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbarnosort.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>76</category_id></action>
            </block>
```